# Ng-zorro Tree With Lazy loading and selection

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

Currently, I started using ng-zorro tree component,
For lazily loading per-node data we can write following template:

```
<nz-tree [nzData]="nodes" nzAsyncData (nzClick)="nzEvent($event)" (nzExpandChange)="nzEvent($event)"> </nz-tree>
```

In TS file we can handle nzExpandChange event and load child nodes appropriately.

What if I want to load tree in Edit-Mode and pre-populate all selected nodes in Edit-Mode of the tree and lazily load other nodes.

I have ids of selected nodes child/parent node. How should I proceed with this?

In short-term I am trying to load all parent nodes and selected child nodes on initialization of component and load other child data based on the click of a parent node